# How do I send a delete request with ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, network-protocols, asihttprequest

Wondering how I can send a DELETE instead of POST/GET etc with ASIHTTPRequest.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`-[ASIHTTPRequest setRequestMethod:]`](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIHTTPRequest.h#L810)?